# When does ruby parse int in yaml

Tags: ruby, yaml

I created this example yaml:

```yaml
---
01:
  01:
    "01"
  02:
    "02"
  03:
    "03"
  04:
    "04"
  05:
    "05"
  06:
    "06"
  07:
    "07"
  08:
    "08"
  09:
    "09"
  10:
    "10"
  11:
    "11"
```

When I read this file like the following

```rb
require 'yaml'

yml = YAML.load_file(File.join('/home/user', 'test.yml'))
p yml
```

the output is

```rb
{1=>{1=>"01", 2=>"02", 3=>"03", 4=>"04", 5=>"05", 6=>"06", 7=>"07", "08"=>"08", "09"=>"09", 10=>"10", 11=>"11"}}
```

Now my question is:
Why are the keys 1 until 7 parsed as int while the keys 08 and 09 are not parsed as int by rubys yaml-parser but as string, i.e. `"08"` and `"09"` respectively?

I am using ruby 3.0.2

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby. YAML is fairly flexible in when it forces you to quote strings or not. Basically, anytime a bare word *cannot possibly be* something else, it is interpreted as a string. Your first 7 keys are legal YAML integers, so they are interpreted as integers. Your last 4 keys are not legal YAML integers, so YAML interprets them as strings. Similarly, for example, YAML interprets `true` as a boolean but `tru` as a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keys `00` to `07` are parsed as octal digits because of the leading `0`. Examples:

```
00
#=> 0
05 
#=> 5
07 
#=> 7
```

`08` and `09` are simply invalid octal digits, and therefore the parser returns those keys in their string representation. Example:

```
08
#=> Invalid octal digit (SyntaxError)
09
#=> Invalid octal digit (SyntaxError)
```